# WPF app using UWP libraries, "could not load file or assembly"

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, porting

i'm currently in the process of implementing BLE support in an existing WPF application. with there being no official support i decided to try and hack in the UWP API's. Im working in visual studio 2017.

when i create a new WPF application and use my class library everything is okay, however when i try to implement it in the existing application i get the following error for every uwp api called.

> Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'Path\to\project\bin\Debug\Windows.UI.Core.AnimationMetrics.AnimationMetricsContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

looking at other threads on stackoverflow i see that it might be an issue with clickonce publishing, where they added

```
<TargetPlatformVersion>8.0</TargetPlatformVersion>
```

to the class library .csproj file, but where do i add that?
in the class library .csproj i only see the line

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

anyone have an idea how i can get this to compile?

Comment: Did you check the x86/x64 bit option?

Comment: yep, this happens in the x86, x64 and any configurations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end i went trough all the projects and found one that was distributed with clickonce.

following https://stackoverflow.com/a/29826962/7097407 i Edited the .Csjproj file and changed

```
<GenerateManifests>true</GenerateManifests>
```

to

```
<GenerateManifests>false</GenerateManifests>
```

and lo and behold my project compiled